# TaskCanceledException with ContinueWith

Tags: c#, .net, task

I've been trying to figure out why I'm getting a TaskCanceledException for a bit of async code that has recently started misbehaving. I've reduced my issue down to a small code snippet that has me scratching my head:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RunTest();
}

private static void RunTest()
{
    Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("{0}", t.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted).Wait();
}
```

As far as I'm aware, this should simply pause for a second and then close. The ContinueWith won't be called (this only applies to my actual use-case). However, instead I'm getting a TaskCanceledException and I've no idea where that is coming from!

Comment: It is related to your taskcontinuationoptions if you change it to none it works.

Comment: The continuation task returned from `ContinueWith` is cancelled because the parent task didn't fault. You need to separate the parent and continuation tasks in this case and wait for the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong taskcontinuationoption:

See following link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

It says :
Specifies that the continuation task should be scheduled only if its antecedent threw an unhandled exception. This option is not valid for multi-task continuations.

Answer (score 3):

I also received this error:

[image: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: 'A task was canceled.']

The block of code looked like this:

```cs
private void CallMediator<TRequest>(TRequest request) where TRequest : IRequest<Unit>
{
    _ = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var mediator = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetService<IMediator>()!;
        await mediator.Send(request).ContinueWith(LogException, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
    });
}

private void LogException(Task task)
{
    if (task.Exception != null)
    {
        _logger.LogError(task.Exception, "{ErrorMessage}", task.Exception.Message);
    }
}
```

Reading the documentation for the [ContinueWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?view=net-6.0#system-threading-tasks-task-continuewith(system-action((system-threading-tasks-task))-system-threading-tasks-taskcontinuationoptions)) method, it has the following remarks:

> The returned Task will not be scheduled for execution until the current task has completed. If the continuation criteria specified through the `continuationOptions` parameter are not met, **the continuation task will be canceled instead** of scheduled.

So for me, it called the first task (`mediator.Send(request)`), then it continued with the task `ContinueWith(...)`, which is the one I `await`ed. However, since an exception had not occurred in the first task, the second task was cancelled. Therefore, when awaiting the second task, it threw a `TaskCanceledException`.

What I did, was to change the code to this:

```cs
private void CallMediator<TRequest>(TRequest request) where TRequest : IRequest<Unit>
{
    _ = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var mediator = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetService<IMediator>()!;
        try
        {
            _ = await mediator.Send(request);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "{ErrorMessage}", ex.Message);
        }
    });
}
```

Instead of using `.ContinueWith(...)`, I have replaced it with just a regular try-catch block in case of the task I am interested in fails. I think this simplifies the code and makes it more readable.

In the question, there is this line of code:

```cs
Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("{0}", t.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted).Wait();
```

I would rewrite it to:

```cs
try
{
    Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", ex);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As guys said above this call requires just antecedent-task in faulted-status otherwise will throw TaskCanceledException, for this concrete case you can generalize ContinueWith to process all statuses:

```
await Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(
    task => 
        {
            /* take into account that Canceled-task throw on next row the TaskCancelledException */

            if (!task.IsFaulted) {
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("{0}", task.Exception);
            // do smth like 'throw task.Exception.InnerException'
        });
```